# How To Get User Location when App is Background with Service?

Tags: android, service

Hello I'm working on a app which is getting user location in background and sending it to firebase database. When app is on foreground everything works fine, but when I get app to the background location is not refreshing it's trying to get location but it gave always same location.
Here is my code:

```
    private void fn_getlocation() {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    isGPSEnable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    isNetworkEnable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if (!isGPSEnable && !isNetworkEnable) {

    } else {

        if (isNetworkEnable) {
            location = null;
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
                if (locationManager!=null){
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location!=null){

                        Log.e("latitude",location.getLatitude()+"");
                        Log.e("longitude",location.getLongitude()+"");

                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        fn_update(location);
                    }
                }
            }

        }else if (isGPSEnable){
            location = null;
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1000,0,this);
            if (locationManager!=null){
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                if (location!=null){
                    Log.e("latitude",location.getLatitude()+"");
                    Log.e("longitude",location.getLongitude()+"");
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    fn_update(location);
                }
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: I ran into the same problem. I did not find the solution with this approach. But this library manage location well in background https://github.com/mrmans0n/smart-location-lib

Comment: Thanks but it's still same.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've found the solution. There is a option in Android Oreo for optimizing the battery. This option trying to stop background tasks of apps. So you need to go to **App Informations>Battery>Battery Optimization>Uncheck Your App**